# Passing array/list of object/struct from C# Library to C++ MFC application

Tags: c#, c++, struct, unmanaged, dllexport

I'm trying to pass an array of object or struct from a C# library (.net 4.5) called by a C++ MFC application but I can't get correct data. An additional difficulty is that C++ application don't know the object count.

I have successfully passed simple type (int, string) and also a struct with the following code (using UnmanagedExports 1.2.7):

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 4)]
public struct ItemA
{
    // Size: 4
    public int Id;
    // Size: 100
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
    public string Name;
    // Size: 2(4)
    public bool IsEnabled;
}

[DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static public IntPtr GetItemA(int itemId)
{
    // Check structure size
    Debug.Assert(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ItemA)) == 108);

    // Get ItemA from a WS
    var itemA = client.GetItemsA().First(i => i.Id == itemId);

    // Convert ItemA to structure pointer
    IntPtr buf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(itemA));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(itemA, buf, false);
    return buf;
}
```

C++

```
#pragma pack(4)
typedef struct
{
    // Size: 4
    int Id;
    // Size: 100
    TCHAR Name[50];
    // Size: 2(4)
    bool IsEnabled;
} ItemA;

extern "C"
{
    ItemA* GetItemA(int itemId);
}

// (...)

void CMyAppDlg::OnBnClickedButtonGetItemA()
{
    // Check structure size
    static_assert(sizeof ItemA == 108, "Size does not match C# struct size");
    ItemA* structItemA = GetItemA(1);    
}
```

I have searched everywhere but I don't find any functionnal response to my specific problem. Can you help to write both C# and C++ codes for GetItemAList which can return an array of struct or another type to C++ application?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit1 :** I changed my code to solve packing/size struct issue (64 bits compilation).

**Edit2 :** I replace manual alignment by #pragma pack.

**Edit3 :** I'm always stuck with GetItemAList. Here is my actual c#/c++ codes with an MemoryException after calling c#. Can you help me with this sh**? Thanks in advance.

C#

```
[DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static public void GetItemAList([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeParamIndex = 1)] ref ItemA[] myArray, ref int length)
{
    // Get ItemAList from a WS
    var itemAArray = client.GetItemsAList().ToArray();

    // Set myArray values
    length = itemAArray.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
         myArray[i] = itemAArray[i];
    }
}
```

C++

```
extern "C"
{
    void GetItemAList(ItemA*& myArray, int& length);
}

// (...)

void CMyAppDlg::OnBnClickedButtonGetItemA()
{
    ItemA* myArray = new ItemA[100];
    int length = 100;
    GetItemAList(myArray, length);   
}
```

Comment: There is no packing specified in the C++ version and I think that C# bool maps on Win32 BOOL.

Comment: Indeed for packing but bool mapping is correct. However, GetItemA is functional and working very well ; my current issue is about GetItemAList :-\

Comment: Then if your problem is with `GetItemAList`, where is the declaration for that function in your question?

Comment: Have you check the actual size of your structure on both side of the fence. **When doing that kind of stuff, you should always do that kind of validation!**

Comment: GetItemA() right now works by accident.  Never the kind of feature of software anyone should strongly pursue, it is pretty fundamental UB in a C or C++ program.  The code also leaks like a sieve.  If you write this code so it works well in C then it will automatically also work well when you interop.  An obvious way to do this is to pass an ItemA[] as an argument, along with the size of that array, so the C# code can simply fill in that array and return the actual size.  Now that UB starts to matter a great, great deal, you just can arrive at the correct code when it is broken off the bat.

Comment: Thanks for your answers about packing. I changed my C++ and C# code (pack attribute, struct declarations, etc.) and add validation to check.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you show me an C#/C++ example to pass an ItemA[] when C++ don't know the array item count return by C# method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done any checking, but your C++ version is probably compiled with 4 bytes packing (assuming your are compiling in 32 bits).

In that case, you would have on C++ side:

```
// Field,   Field size, Total size
// -------------------------------
// Id,               0,          4
// Name,            50,         54
// IsEnabled,        1,         55
// (padding)         1,         56
```

On that side, you should add a `static_assert` validating that you got the expected size.

```
static_check(sizeof ItemA == 56, "Size does not match C# struct size")
```

On the hand on C# side, you would have:

```
// Field,   Field size, Total size
// -------------------------------
// Id,               0,          4
// Name,            50,         54
// IsEnabled,        4,         58
// (no padding)      0,         58
```

And if `bool` was 1 byte, you would have a size of 55 instead. In both case, it would not match the size on C++ side.

As it is somewhat hard to know all rules and not make any mistake and also to ensure nothing is broken in future maintenance, **you should always add validation in your code.**

On C# side, typical validation would be something like: `Debug.Assert(Marshal.Sizeof(typeof(ItemA)) == 58`.

You could also validate the offset or size of some fields but generally if the size you compute by hand do match on both sides, you probably got it right particularily if you use 1 byte packing.

Comment: Obviously, size on both sides must match. You have do any necessary adjustment on the desired side. If you have the choice, you should try to have your structure fields naturally aligned (and explicitly add padding bytes). Also in such case, it might be a good idea to write the size information at the end of each line to ease future maintenance if you need to add some fields.

Comment: You were right about packing: size on both sides didn't match. I did some adjustments to correct struct declarations on C++ and C# and also packing attribute in C#.